# Cantor cubes are universal for totally disconnected compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness, separation-axioms, cantor-set

Can anyone tell me how to show that a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of a product of discrete two-point spaces? I cannot think of a known example of such space, so I am not able to proceed through my intuition.

Comment: The Cantor set is an example (or any convergent sequence including the limit point).

Comment: @Martin Thank you very much

Comment: Paul Halmos' book _Lectures on Boolean Algbras_ has quite a bit on this.  The category of totally disconnected compact Hausdorff spaces and continuous functions is the opposite of the category of Boolean algebras and homomorphisms.  The set of homomorphisms from a Boolean algebra to the two-member Boolean algebra, with the topology of pointwise convergence of nets of homomorphisms, is a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space.  And the set of all of clopen subsets of a totally disconnected is a Boolean algebra.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HINT: For each clopen set $H\subseteq X$ the function

$$f_H:X\to\{0,1\}:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }x\in H\\
0,&\text{if }x\notin H
\end{cases}$$

is a continuous function from $X$ to the discrete two-point space. Let $\mathscr{H}$ be the set of all clopen subsets of $X$, and for each $H\in\mathscr{H}$ let $D_H$ be a copy of the discrete two-point space. Define a map

$$\varphi:X\to\prod_{H\in\mathscr{H}}D_H:x\mapsto\langle f_H(x):H\in\mathscr{H}\rangle\;,$$

and show that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ onto $\varphi[X]$.

Comment: What do you mean by $D_H$ the copy of the discrete two-point space?